# Подсчет количества результатов после if elif в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, условия

Хочу сделать чтобы выводились подсчитанные результаты после `if` `elif`.

```
if sock.connect_ex((mn['ip'], mn['port'])) == 0:
    print('%s:%d - open' % (mn['ip'], mn['port']))               
    if "1.1.1.1"<=mn['ip']<="2.2.2.2":
        print("1")
    elif "2.2.2.2"<=mn['ip']<="3.3.3.3":
        print("2")
    elif "3.3.3.3"<=mn['ip']<="4.4.4.4":
        print("3")
    elif "4.4.4.4"<=mn['ip']<="5.5.5.5":
        print("4")
    conn.commit()
```

Хотелось бы чтобы выводило сколько всего `print("1")` `print("2")` `print("3")` `print("4")`

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` там где у вас `1.1.1.1` должны быть строки, например "1.1.1.1", исправьте в вопросе

Comment: Создавайте четыре числовых переменных и считайте в них результат, в чём проблема-то

Comment: @andreymal говорю же только начал изучать, подскажите пожалуйста как правильней это сделать

Comment: @Gy9vin про переменные и про числа вроде рассказывают в первых главах любого учебника про Python

Answer (score 2):

Заводите счетчики, определяете условия и подсчитывайте:

```
# Пример: '1.1.1.1' -> 1111
def ip_to_int(ip: str) -> int:
    return int(ip.replace('.', ''))

# Возвращает True, если IP входит в указанный диапазон
def ip_in(ip: str, ip_start: str, ip_end: str) -> bool:
    return ip_to_int(ip_start) <= ip_to_int(ip) <= ip_to_int(ip_end)

# ...

ip = mn['ip']
port = mn['port']

if sock.connect_ex((ip, port)) == 0:
    print('%s:%d - open' % (ip, port))

    # Счетчики
    number_1 = 0
    number_2 = 0
    number_3 = 0
    number_4 = 0
    
    if ip_in(ip, "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"):
        number_1 += 1
    elif ip_in(ip, "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"):
        number_2 += 1
    elif ip_in(ip, "3.3.3.3", "4.4.4.4"):
        number_3 += 1
    elif ip_in(ip, "4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5"):
        number_4 += 1

    print('1:', number_1)
    print('2:', number_2)
    print('3:', number_3)
    print('4:', number_4)

    conn.commit()
```

---

**PS.**

Способом проверки IP тут использовал представление его в качестве числа, например проверка

```
if "1.1.1.1" <= "1.2.3.4" <= "2.2.2.2":
```

будет представлена как:

```
if 1111 <= 1234 <= 2222:
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так: создаёте четыре переменные-счётчика

```
iter1 = iter2 = iter3 = iter4 = 0
```

Инкрементируете соответствующий счётчик, если условие выполнилось:

```
if sock.connect_ex((mn['ip'], mn['port'])) == 0:
    print('%s:%d - open' % (mn['ip'], mn['port']))               
    if "1.1.1.1"<=mn['ip']<="2.2.2.2":
        iter1 += 1
    elif "2.2.2.2"<=mn['ip']<="3.3.3.3":
        iter2 += 1
    elif "3.3.3.3"<=mn['ip']<="4.4.4.4":
        iter3 += 1
    elif "4.4.4.4"<=mn['ip']<="5.5.5.5":
        iter4 += 1
    conn.commit()
```

Выводите значения счётчиков

```
print(iter1, iter2, iter3, iter4)
```

Comment: спасибо. Объявил их еще глобальными и все заработало